# Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using odbc driver 13.1 for Ubuntu 16.04 with pyodbc (pyodbc==4.0.21
). Every thing works and sometimes randomly I get this error

"Server Error  ('08S01', u'[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

I followed the instructions from microsoft docs:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/02/04/odbc-driver-13-1-for-linux-released/

Another error that I get is :
pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'lastrowid odbc13
When I try to save to db.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As suggested in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/2#issuecomment-26678867), you may want to try updating UnixODBC to the latest version.

Comment: As sugested in microsoft docs, I did an apt-get update and then apt-get install unixodbc-dev. So it is the latest version installed.

Comment: The versions of software in the Ubuntu repositories can be quite old. You could check the UnixODBC website to see what the latest version really is.

Comment: unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.1-4.1)
And on the official site: News
31.Aug.2015 2.3.4 Released
You think that the 08S01 Error will be solved by upgrading to 2.3.4 ? This error happens randomly and I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did anyone solved this issue? I am running in the same problem with flask, pyodbc, sqlalchemy